# Windows Phone: To search for places in HERE Maps

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, maps, here-api

`GeocodeQuery` only gives location results. I want to search the word "restaurants" providing my current coordinates and get all the restuarants in the result. Just like actual HERE Maps work. How can I achieve it?

```
   MyGeocodeQuery = new GeocodeQuery();
   MyGeocodeQuery.SearchTerm = searchTerm;
   MyGeocodeQuery.GeoCoordinate = MyCoordinate == null ? new GeoCoordinate(0, 0) :     MyCoordinate;
   MyGeocodeQuery.QueryCompleted += GeocodeQuery_QueryCompleted;
   MyGeocodeQuery.QueryAsync();
```

This gives only location results and not places.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MapTask` for it.

```
  MapsTask mapsTask = new MapsTask();
  //Omit the Center property to use the user's current location.
  //mapsTask.Center = new GeoCoordinate(47.6204, -122.3493);
  mapsTask.SearchTerm = "coffee";
  mapsTask.ZoomLevel = 2;
  mapsTask.Show();
```

For more Reference you can go here [How to use the Maps task for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206989(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: Hi. But these are launchers. I want a query result of the text search. Any leads on that?

Comment: have you gone through this ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj244363(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [`API`](http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/Lumia/change-history/archived-content/maps-and-navigation/here-launchers/here-launchers-api-reference.html) reference, use ExploremapsSearchPlacesTask

```
ExploremapsSearchPlacesTask searchMap = new ExploremapsSearchPlacesTask();
searchMap.Location = new GeoCoordinate(60.35, 24.60);
searchMap.SearchTerm = "Restaurants";
searchMap.Show();
```

Comment: Hi. But these are launchers. I want a query result of the text search. Any leads on that?